# How to merge two dataframes with different column names but same number of rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different data frames in pandas. Example:

```
df1=a b  df2= c
    0 1       1 
    1 2       2 
    2 3       3
```

I want to merge them so

```
df1= a b c  
     0 1 1
     1 2 2
     2 3 3
```

I tried using `df1['c'] = df2['c']` but i got a settingwithCopywarnings

Comment: is column `a` the index?

Answer (score 2):

In order to merge two dataframes you can use this two examples. Both returns the same goal.

Using `merge` plus additional arguments instructing it to use the indexes

Try this:

```
response = pandas.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
In [2]: response
Out[2]:
    b   c
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3   3
```

Or you can use `join`. In case your daraframes are differently-indexed.

> DataFrame.join is a convenient method for combining the columns of two potentially differently-indexed DataFrames into a single result DataFrame.

Here is a basic example:

```
result = df1.join(df2)
In [3]: result
Out[3]:
    b   c
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3   3
```